# PHPEXCEL : php excel only show 1 letter

Tags: php, sql, excel

Please help me on the PHPEXCEL. it shows only one letter.
this is my php code:

```
$sql_question   =   "SELECT * FROM tna_question WHERE title_id = '$tid' ORDER BY section_id";

$result_question    =   mysql_query($sql_question, $db);

$category   =   array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_question)) {
    $arr1   =   $row['question'];
    $arr    =   array_push($category ,$arr1);
    $category_count++;
}

$arr3[]     =   $category;
```

the result from the sql query is an array:

```
Array ( [0] => gfhgfh [1] => gfhfg [2] => fggfdg [3] => fds [4] => asd [5] => fghgfh [6] => Policy Wordings / Coverage [7] => Risk Assessment / Survey & Underwriting [8] => Policy Wordings / Coverage [9] => Risk Assessment / Survey & Underwriting )
```

when i use this line:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->fromArray($category, NULL, 'C7');
```

it gives me only the first letter from each row

[image]

but if i make this one:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->fromArray($arr3, NULL, 'C7');
```

it'll give all the data in one row.
[image]

but The output that i want is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to get the desired result :

```
foreach($arr3 as $k => $v){
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $k, $v); 
}
```

**Note** : Changing the column value will make it go left and right only. In case you want to shift the entire thing down then replace $k by $k+$val where $val is the number of rows you want to shift down.

Comment: i got this : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate

Comment: what is $k, $col, $v basicly?

Comment: @airi did you set the active sheet? And what value are you using for `$col`?

Comment: @airi `$k` is the row number, `$col` is the column number and `$v` is the value you want to enter into that cell.

Comment: Following the code from @AkshatSinghal, you might want to set the value of $k to 7 and the value of $col to "3". That way you'll start from "C7".

Comment: Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: still i got the 2nd pic .. i want like first pics

Comment: i cannot use $arr3 but if i used $category it work fine but still it will show as second pics.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Replace `$arr[] = $category` by `$arr = $category` and then try.

Comment: yes that will do the trick.. but still the problems remain..it only show first letter only. like the first pics.

Comment: @airi Can you please post a screenshot/ image of what you want exactly?

Comment: i want the the excel show like first pic but with whole data not only show first letter.. ok i post the pic that i want

Comment: hi.. it works. the data display .. how can i change $col to A7 something like that ... it only can go left and right cannot go down..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46890/discussion-between-akshat-singhal-and-airi)